# Update page with new data in Django

Tags: ajax, django

Let's imagine I have a Django app which can create and display some kind of articles which are stored in DB. Every article has a status value which means if *status*=1, it should be displayed, if *status*=0, it shouldn't.

I create articles on some page of my app, and by default it's *status* is 1. In the other tab the other page is opened. Every N seconds it sends AJAX requests with the ids of currently displayed articles and gets response with the id and content of new articles which are not displayed yet.

The question is - how can I dynamically render divs for new articles and fill them with data from response, if I don't want to create HTML-markup in *success* function of AJAX request with *append()* function or some kind of that stuff? I.e. I create article in one tab and it instantly displays in the other tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a template with all new articles:

```
def new_article_view(request):
    old_ids = request.query_params.get('ids')
    new_articles = Articles.objects.exclude(id__in=old_ids.split(','))
    # this render your template for Articles list.
    return render(request, {'new_articles':new_articles}
```

then in your javascript code you most push the html returned by the django view in the end of the div or something like that.